# hibernate: join table

Tags: hibernate

I'm not sure how to join tables in hibernate. Say i have a table called `news` and another table as `news_categories`. The `news` table has a primary key as id, which also serves as a foreign key for table `news_categories`. Now i need to find out the categories for each `news` in the `news` table, how can i do that in hibernate?

here is my code to get the news:

```
HibernateEntityManagerFactory hmf = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) _emf;
SessionFactory sf = hmf.getSessionFactory();
Session ss = sf.openSession();

ScrollableResults srq = ss.createCriteria(news.class)
            .addOrder(Order.desc(("_creationDate")))
            .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
            .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
..
```

Comment: You shouldn't think of Hibernate queries in terms of the database tables. Think of them in terms of your object model. What does your object model look like?

Comment: '@FetchProfile(name="batch-fetch"), fetchOverrides={@FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = News.class, association="categories", mode=FetchMode.JOIN)}) @FetchProfile(name="batch-fetch"), fetchOverrides={@FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = News.class, association="categories", mode=FetchMode.JOIN)}) public class News implement Seriable { @Id @Column(name="newsid") private String id; @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @CollectionTable(name="NEWS_CATEGORIES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="NEWSID")) @Column(name="CATID") private Set<String> categories;

Answer (score 0):

on srq add `.createAlias("newsCategories")`

This way the the categories will be fetched together with the news items.